# Call azure function from another azure function in javascript

Tags: azure, function, invoke

I am new in Azure technology. I have created two functions Master (**masterFunction**) and Child (**childFunction**) in Javascript.

I want to invoke Child function from Master function.

I have tried with `childFunction.Run(req, log);` but its not working.

Please suggest me to fix above issue.
Thanks

Comment: You need to meet the trigger conditions of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work, the azure function actually executes code to meet the trigger conditions. For example, if your childfunction is triggered by a blob, then the way your masterfunction calls it is to satisfy the trigger condition of the childfunction, that is, add operations to the target blob in your masterfunction. If your childfunction is http, then you need to send a request to the childfunction url in the code of the masterfunction.

Comment: Do you mean call child function from master using http request correct?
Could you please provide me syntax for the same?
I have tried with below one but not working

var options = {
            path: 'http://localhost:7071/api/childFunction',
            method: 'POST'
        };
                
        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
             context.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);    
        });

Thanks